# The name of the default android browser

Tags: browser, stock-browser

does anyone know if the standard Android browser that comes pre-installed on the cell phones has its own name? Every browser on the market has one - Safari, FF, Fennec, Dolphin, etc. But the "standard android browser" seems lacking it. Or I'm wrong?

I'm writing small blog posts about JavaScript and Android and I'm really tired of writing "Standard Android browser works differently from Fennec" instead of "Foobar works differently from Fennec"

Comment: "Default" is another adjective you could use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not as far as I know; it's name is just "Browser". To distinguish it from the other browsers, sometimes I call it "stock browser".

btw, it's called Firefox now (or Firefox Mobile), and no longer Fennec.

Comment: I've also seen the Android Browser referred to as...the Android Browser.

Comment: @AlEverett: I've seen that too, but IMO that is still kinda ambiguous that Android Browser does not mean the other browsers, especially in an article which also mentions browsers in other OSes.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a ActivityManager to get the message about process

in my phone,Browser is "com.android.browser",it's the same in all the android.

Is different OS,the name we see may be different , like different language,and so on.

In English,it's Browser.

Hope the answer is useful.