# What is the name/version number of the stock browser that comes on Android 2.3?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, stock-browser

I am doing research on mobile web design for an upcoming project and part of what I need to find is the marketshare of mobile browsers so we can determine which ones we will support. I have found statistics of mobile browser marketshare but I now need to clarify exactly what I am seeing.

I see statistics for "Android Browser 4.0" and I *assume* it is the stock browser for Android 4.x devices. But if that were true I would expect to see statistics for an "Android Browser 2.0" or "Android Browser 3.0" in the statistics but I do not. I can't imagine that all Android 2.x users don't surf the Internet or use non-default browsers so it appears that my assumption is incorrect.

So what is the name/version number of the stock browser in Android 2.3 (or all 2.x) devices?

Comment: Did you see this? [The name of the default android browser](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/14869)

Comment: I guess what I should say is, "What is the version number"? I'll clarify my question now.

Comment: Do you have one? http://whatsmyuseragent.com/ might be helpful. (My Galaxy Nexus reports "Android/4.2.2", which matches the current version of my OS.)

Answer (score 1):

Please see this link on wikipedia:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_version_history

See **usage share** wikipedia reference, obtaining user agent and application is not straight forward.

- Many Android browsers identify themselves as Safari on iOS (among
  other things) in order to aid compatibility
- Many Linux Browsers identify themselves as Safari on Mac OS X
  (among other things) in order to aid compatibility

When I  use **Dolphin** my user agent does not show anything resembling Gingerbread 2.3.4 or my browser.  The following is by default though I can change my user agent that's part of using a browser.

**Dolphin** showing as a **mobile device**:
**User Agent:** Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.3.4; en-us; A1_07 Build/GRJ22) AppleWebKit/533.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/533.1

**Dolphin** with user agent as **desktop**:
**User Agent:** Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_3; en-us) AppleWebKit/533.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.0 Safari/533.1

For the **default Android browser** on my tablet:
**User Agent:** Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.3.4; en-us; A1_07 Build/GRJ22) AppleWebKit/533.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/533.1

And for **Firefox**
**User Agent:** on my tablet
Mozilla/5.0 (Android; Mobile; rv:31.0) Gecko/31.0 Firefox/31.0

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usage_share_of_web_browsers
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Browser_sniffing

To go much beyond general user oriented information/interest, you would have find out more from developers.